# Google Play: Beta release to Production release

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play, google-play-console

We recently decided to update our new application for [Beta release](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/launch/test-tracks) on google play,

Now after reading the guide, there were some questions that I had in my mind and wanted to know more about them, I googled for further understanding found some answers but there are still somethings that I wasn't sure about so decided to put this question up:

- For Beta releases is it possible to make a beta release that is available to all the google play users(as a normal production app) or will it be available to all?
  (Since as per this guide it gives me an idea that the application will only be available to a set amount of users.)

> **Make sure users can join the tests.** Your testers will need to have a Google account (@gmail.com) or a G Suite account to join a test.
>
> **Run tests internally.** Use the internal testing track to push your app to up to 100 internal testers in seconds.

- Once I release a beta application and I decide to now put it for production, will it be uploaded as a different application or the same also will the comments that were posted to the beta release google play app be visible on my production app?
  (Didn't quite get anything in relation to this one.)
- In one of the points, it said that my application should have a higher version code in the beta release then that of the production release, But if I have a higher version in that release would it not be the application that will be getting downloaded even when it might not be the most stable version?  (this one actually confused me big time)

> **Check your Android App Bundle version number.** For an app on the internal, closed, or open testing tracks to be available to testers, it must have a higher version code than your production version.

- Is there a designated field where I can provide this email for the beta testers or can I just provide it in the description of the application?

> **Provide a channel for testers to send you feedback.** For closed tests, offer testers the ability to provide feedback by email, at a website, in a message forum, or through another suitable mechanism.

Comment: I know it might not be the answer you were looking for, but you can get the best answeres to your questions by asking them to Google Play developer support.https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> For Beta releases is it possible to make a beta release that is available to all the google play users

You can release your app as an Open Beta, which anyone who wants can get access to (without being invited by you). See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en  (specifically the part *Step 1: Set up test details - Open test: surface your test app on Google Play*)

> Once I release a beta application and I decide to now put it for production, will it be uploaded as a different application or the same

Same. There's no re-uploading - you just change the state of the release.

> also will the comments that were posted to the beta release google play app be visible on my production app?

Testers can't leave public reviews on Google Play.

> But if I have a higher version in that release would it not be the application that will be getting downloaded even when it might not be the most stable version?

Well, that's the point.They have opted in to be testers of your app, so they get the latest available version. If they want to revert back to only getting production versions they can opt out of the test program.

> Is there a designated field where I can provide this email for the beta testers or can I just provide it in the description of the application?

This is explained on the page I linked to: *Next to "Feedback channel," add an email address or URL to collect feedback from testers. Your app's feedback channel will be shown to users on your tester opt-in page.*

Comment: I have made a small change in the question and added one more can you please address that as well?

Comment: Important **INFO about ROLL-OUT TIME**. If you published your app to beta-channel breforehand and then click "RELEASE TO PRODUCTION" button, do not expect it will be roll out immediately, it will **still take up to 24 HOURS** to be live.

Comment: Explained clearly.

Answer (score 8):

Beta releases are just a different track on your app's page.

If you have a public beta program (you'll need to select that as your type), users will see a "Join Beta Program" card somewhere on your app's Play Store page when they visit it. This card should show up below the "Developer Contact" information.

If a user decides to join the beta program, they'll get any new versions you publish there just like a normal update. *Beta users cannot leave reviews!* Beta users can leave you, the developer, private comments, but unless they leave the beta program, they can't create a review or edit an existing one.

Once you promote your beta build to production, it'll be available to all users of your app as a normal update. Beta users won't receive an update, since they're already on the version you promoted, nor will they be pushed out of the beta program. If you upload an APK straight to production, beta users will receive it as well (they still won't be able to leave a review).

As for version numbers, you can't upload another APK to the Play Console unless it has a later version code than the latest one already uploaded. If you have version 7 in your production channel, you can't upload a new APK with version 7 to beta; it has to be version 8.

Comment: If application is `Open Test` Find desired application on the GooglePlay Store and see is  details > scroll down to the bottom > click button `Join open test`

Answer (score 6):

When you upload your app as a Beta version, The users who joined your beta testing can upgrade to that version. The other users who have not joined beta testing, will no see any update for your app.

When you want to make the beta version as a production release, you can do so by simply clicking on **Promote to Production** option on Google Play Store.

With concern to your confusion, when you have some apk in beta version (say versionCode 2), then you can promote that app as a production, or you can also upload another apk as a production but remember, that should have greater version code (say 3). If you do so, then all users will get that update including beta testers. That will be an update to the same app.(I think you're doubtful here) Hope this helps.