# Is there any way to set custom version name for flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I want to set version name of app something like 1.0.4 beta +4.
but it's not possible. Is there any solution for this kind of versioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply typing the desired version name in build.gradle app module worked.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 33
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName 1.1.1.custom // here change flutterVersionName to custom version name
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So unlike a lot of other platforms, mobile platforms don't allow you to have whatever you like as version codes.

If you read about versioning on Android https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning and the iOS info plist https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list you will find that the only allowed characters are `0-9` and `.`

Generally how you handle beta tests in iOS and Android is by having a separate build and identifying it with the "beta" keyword in the identifier itself

So if your app is generally identified with the following bundle id `com.companyname.app` its beta release would be `com.companyname.app.beta`

Also, there are other ways like the beta release on Google Stores and TestFlight but I wanted the premise to be clear, you can also check out this for a better understanding of how google stores releases work [Google Play: Beta release to Production release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52760808/google-play-beta-release-to-production-release)

Comment: Actually it's not beta release. I want to make two different releases of one code base. one for tv and one for mobile and I want to annotate tv on the version name of tv releases.

Comment: From my experience as a mobile eng you can't do this, if you wanna differentiate you define different bundle id's